# Calculate the difference between two dates in hours:minutes:seconds?

Tags: java, android

How can I calculate the difference between two dates and show it in the format hours:minutes:seconds?

Example:

```
StartTime : 2016-12-20T04:30  
EndTime   : 2016-12-22T05:00
```

The output should be `"48hours 30minutes 0 seconds"`.

This is what I've tried:

```java
Long diff = (endDate.get time() -startDate.gettime())/1000;    

Log.d("App","difference in hour is"+diff/1000/60/60);
Mins = diff/1000/60;
Seconds = diff/1000;
```

Using this code I'm getting hours as a correct value. But the minute and seconds values are not getting their proper values.

Comment: What you tried so far ??? search on google

Comment: Long diff = (endDate.get time() -startDate.gettime())/1000
Log.d("App","difference in hour is"+diff/1000/60/60)
Mins = diff/1000/60
Seconds = diff/1000.. using this code im getting hours as a correct value. But the minute and seconds value are not getting properly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this function:-

```
//1 minute = 60 seconds
//1 hour = 60 x 60 = 3600
//1 day = 3600 x 24 = 86400
public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

    //milliseconds
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
    System.out.println("different : " + different);

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    //long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    //different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    System.out.printf(
        "%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
        elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

**1.** Add following methods first, then use parseDate.

```
Date startDate = parseDate("2016-12-20T04:30");
Date endDate = parseDate("2016-12-22T05:00");
```

**2.** Calculate difference b/w these two

```
long differenceInMillis = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

**3.** Use formatElapsedTime method to formatted difference

```
String formattedText = formatElapsedTime(differenceInMillis/1000); //divide by 1000 to get seconds from milliseconds
//Result will be 48hours 30minutes 0 seconds


public static Date parseDate (String strDate) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
    Date date1 = null;
    try {
        date1 = dateFormat.parse (strDate);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    return date1;
}

public static String formatElapsedTime (long seconds) {

    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds);
    seconds -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds (hours);

    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes (seconds);
    seconds -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds (minutes);

    return String.format ("%dhr:%dmin:%dsec", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: Using the above code : 2016-12-20T04:30
2016-12-22T05:00 

For above two inputs, the answer I'm getting is 48500hour 0min 0sec...

Instead I shud get 48hours 30mins 0 seconds

Comment: I was converting milliseconds, I divided it by 1000 to get seconds and the calculate hours, minutes, and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateDifferenceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creates two calendars instances
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Set the date for both of the calendar instance
        cal1.set(2006, Calendar.DECEMBER, 30);
        cal2.set(2007, Calendar.MAY, 3);

        // Get the represented date in milliseconds
        long millis1 = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
        long millis2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();

        // Calculate difference in milliseconds
        long diff = millis2 - millis1;

        // Calculate difference in seconds
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;

        // Calculate difference in minutes
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);

        // Calculate difference in hours
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

        // Calculate difference in days
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.println("In milliseconds: " + diff + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println("In seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");
        System.out.println("In minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
        System.out.println("In hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
        System.out.println("In days: " + diffDays + " days.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**New answer to an old question using a newer API: `java.time`**

You can write a method that actually accepts the datetimes as `String`s along with a time zone and then calculates the difference by means of a class designed for such purpose: `java.time.Duration`

Here's a code example:

```java
public static String getDifference(String firstDt, String secondDt, String zone) {
    // create the zone for the calculation just to respect daylight saving time
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone);
    // then parse the datetimes passed and add the time zone
    ZonedDateTime firstZdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
                                    LocalDateTime.parse(firstDt), zoneId
                             );
    ZonedDateTime secondZdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
                                    LocalDateTime.parse(secondDt), zoneId
                              );

    // calculate the duration between the two datetimes
    Duration duration;
    
    /*
     * the JavaDocs of Duration tell us the following:
     * 
     * "The result of this method can be a negative period
     * if the end is before the start.".
     * 
     * So we need to make sure the older datetime will be
     * the "start" in the method "between(start, end)"
     */
    if (firstZdt.isAfter(secondZdt)) {
        duration = Duration.between(secondZdt, firstZdt);
    } else {
        duration = Duration.between(firstZdt, secondZdt);
    }

    // store the amount of full hours the duration has
    long hoursBetween;
    hoursBetween = duration.toHours();
    // calculate the minutes left from the full duration in minutes
    long minutesBetween;
    minutesBetween = duration.toMinutes() - (hoursBetween * 60);
    // calculate the seconds left from the full duration in seconds
    long secondsBetween;
    secondsBetween = duration.getSeconds() - (duration.toMinutes() * 60);

    // build the result String, take care of possibly missing leading zeros
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    resultBuilder.append(hoursBetween).append(" hours ");
    if (minutesBetween < 10 && minutesBetween > 0)
        resultBuilder.append("0");
    resultBuilder.append(minutesBetween).append(" minutes ");
    if (secondsBetween < 10 && secondsBetween > 0)
        resultBuilder.append("0");
    resultBuilder.append(secondsBetween).append(" seconds");

    return resultBuilder.toString();
}
```

If you use it in a `main`...

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timeDiff = getDifference("2016-12-20T04:30", "2016-12-22T05:00", "UTC");
    System.out.println(timeDiff);
}
```

... you will get the following output:

```
48 hours 30 minutes 0 seconds
```

The code above is the one to be used in Java 8, later on, `Duration` got the methods `toHoursPart()`, `toMinutesPart()` and `toSecondsPart()` which actually do the necessary calculation internally.

The code that would change (tried with Java 11):

```java
// store the amount of full hours the duration has
long hoursBetween;
hoursBetween = duration.toHoursPart();
// calculate the minutes left from the full duration in minutes
long minutesBetween;
minutesBetween = duration.toMinutesPart();
// calculate the seconds left from the full duration in seconds
long secondsBetween;
secondsBetween = duration.toSecondsPart();
```