# How much time left to X hour in Kotlin

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I want to do, in Kotlin for Android Studio, the following:
Calculate how many hours and minutes left for 10:00AM (Spanish Hour always). So:

- If it's 8:45AM, it returns 1h45m
- If it's 12:00PM, it returns 22h0m

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show it?

Comment: Do you know `java.time`? Do you support API versions below 26?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892644/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-hoursminutesseconds

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this using the JVM, so I'm not sure if it works for Android, but I think the algorithm is correct:

```
fun timeUntilInMadrid(hour: Int): Duration {
    val timezone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")
    val now = ZonedDateTime.now(timezone).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)

    val targetTime = LocalTime.of(hour, 0)
    val targetDate =
        if (now.toLocalTime() <= targetTime) now.toLocalDate()
        else now.toLocalDate().plusDays(1)

    val then = ZonedDateTime.of(targetDate, targetTime, timezone)
    return Duration.between(now, then)
}
```

You can then format the `Duration` however you like. For example:

```
fun main() {
    val duration = timeUntilInMadrid(10)
    println("${duration.toHoursPart()}h${duration.toMinutesPart()}m")
}
```

Output at time of posting:

```
18h40m
```

Comment: Tested your code in Android Kotlin and works except the `toHoursPart` and `toMinutesPart` are introduced in "Android S" which is still in beta.  So replaced with some api 26 functions with : `Log.d("main", "${until.toHours()}h${until.toMinutes()%60}m")` - which should work for durations less than 24 hours.